# Can I display text contained inside an HTML tag as regular page content?

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP application that I use to build Emails.  When the Email is sent, it is a multipart form with both an HTML part and a plain text part.

In order to create the plain text part, I use the PHP strip_tags function on the HTML version of the content, and display the result.  Works just fine.

I now have a situation where I want to say something in the HTML part that I don't want to say in the plain text part. (It's instructions related to an embedded image of a QR code - and the QR code doesn't show in the plain text version of the Email.)

What I was thinking was - if I could somehow embed the instructions in an HTML tag, then the strip_tags function would strip it out.

However, I can't find any HTML tag that contains text that get's displayed, other than the VALUE string in an INPUT or SUBMIT tag, and I don't think creating an input field would work - there is more than a line of text.

I realize that by definition, HTML is supposed to be a "markup language" and therefore separate and independent from the content on the page.  And so I am asking to do something that it really isn't designed to do, but thought I would put it out there to see if anyone happens to have a way to do this, or know that it definitely cannot be done.

Thanks............!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build your HTML content, then generate the plain-text version from it, and then after that is complete add the HTML specific content to the HTML content string?

Another option would be to put some HTML comments around the HTML-only content that you can easily use to strip out that section before you convert to plain-text.